# How to open an exe in asp.net using impersonation

Tags: asp.net

I want to open a file(.exe) at client side which is placed on public network. I can use impersonation but i am not finding any way?

Comment: " i am not finding any way" - to do what?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class with [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) and set the `UserName` and `Password` before starting it.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Path to exe");
startInfo.UserName = "the user to impersonate";
startInfo.Password = "the password in a SecureString";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: suppose my password is PASSWORD startInfo.Password = 'PASSWORD' doesnt work how do i typecast it

Comment: @Ulhas - Take a look at [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx).

Comment: i am getting an error "The stub received bad data" when executing Process.Start(startInfo);